# Setting the responseType in dynamically created HttpClient options

Tags: angular

I am **creating headers** for my http calls like this:

```
private createHeaders(headers: Map<string, string>): HttpHeaders {
    let httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    for (const entry of Array.from(headers.entries())) {
        httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append(entry[0], entry[1]);
    }
    return httpHeaders;
}
```

I am **setting the headers** like this:

```
 createOptions(headers: HttpHeaders) {
        const options = {
            headers: headers,
        }
        return options;
    }
```

Finally I am **making my http GET calls** like this:

```
get<T>(url: string, noLoadingIndicator?: boolean): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(url, this.createOptions(this.createHeaders(
        new Map([['Content-Type', 'application/json'], ['showLoading', noLoadingIndicator ? 'off' : 'on']]
        )
    )));
}
```

This works well. Now I need to **get files** as well, so I did this:

```
getFile(url: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(url, this.createOptionsBlob(
        this.createHeaders(new Map([[ShowLoading, 'on']]
        )
    )));
}

createOptionsBlob(headers: HttpHeaders) {
    const options = {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'blob' as 'blob' // Found this online, not sure how/why this works
    }
    return options;
}
```

As you can see, I had to create a **separate method to create the options to include the responseType**.

I tried to extend createOptions to make it configurable like this:

```
createOptions(headers: HttpHeaders, responseType?: string) {
    const options = {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: responseType
    }
    return options;
}
```

But then I get the following error on the get method:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>     Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

How do I make createOptions work like I want ? The HttpClient documentation did not help me. What am I missing ?

Comment: This 'responseType' can't be a string. It must be a json. You have to type correctly this createOptions(headers: HttpHeaders, responseType?: string) method. This is what means `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.`

Comment: So how do I pass it as a json to my method ?